# Using backticks and pipes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, piping, backticks

This bug appears when using shell commands in a ruby script. The commands are not executed as what would happen in the bash terminal.

The first two commands are reasonable, the third is not.

```
`echo foo` # => "foo\n"
`echo -n foo` # => "foo"
`echo -n foo | cat` # => "-n foo\n"
```

In bash, we would have the following:

```
$ echo foo # => "foo\n"
$ echo -n foo # => "foo"
$ echo -n foo | cat # => "foo"
```

Is there a way I am messing up the parameter passing to the calls to `echo` in the Ruby commands? If you're unfamiliar, the command echo returns the string it is given. Without the `-n` flag, it appends a newline character, when you add the `-n`, it does not. `cat` repeats whatever it is given.

Comment: `ruby -e 'a=\`echo -n foo | cat\`; print a'` works fine here!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It depends on what shell is used for `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, Ruby uses `/bin/sh`, not `bash`, for the back tick operator. It is likely that on your system, `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`, but `bash` behaves differently when invoked as `sh`, for better POSIX compliance. However, it's not perfect, as your example shows. The POSIX specification states that `echo` "shall not support any options", but leaves handling of an initial argument `-n` to be implementation-specific.

In a quick test with `/bin/sh` as a link to `/bin/bash`,
`bash -c "echo -n foo"` and `bash -c "echo -n foo | cat"` produced identical, newline-free results, but `sh -c "echo -n foo"` and `sh -c "echo -n foo | cat"` showed the results you report. (I am not sure how other shells, such as `ksh`, `dash`, or `zsh`, behave when invoked as `sh`, but by default they all treat `-n` as a newline suppressor.)

For predictable results, use `printf` instead, which never prints a newline unless a `\n` is included in the format string.

```
printf 'foo\n'
printf 'foo'
printf 'foo' | cat
```

UPDATE: This appears to be a bug in `bash 3.2` that was fixed at some point in the 4.x series. With 4.1 or later, `sh -c "echo -n foo | cat` and `sh -c "echo -n foo"` produce the same output.